# Delphi Indy LAN Chat

Tags: delphi-2010, indy, delphi

I have a basic indy TCP server and a client in which the client sends messages to the server.  In the `OnConnect` event on the server, the clients IP is added to a list box. I would like to get this list box on the client as well with the list box updating as clients connect and disconnect. I am new to the Indy components and unsure what is the best way to do this?

Comment: [chat example using Indy](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Creating-Chat-Application-with-Borland-DelphiIndy-The-Client/) [and this is very simple to find them](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=indy+chat+example&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Comment: Use UDP broadcast, Luke!

Comment: @user539484 That is really nice tradition to post message like "To solve the problem use <something>" Luke! :) It is not sarcasm in any way, but it is good practice when we are do not give answer like "copy & paste" instead of "learn this". BTW UDP protocol have one big problem: it is not assuming that is packet reached another client. So it must be realized by HTTP, FTP (or any other more safe protocol) In my previous comment second link is explain how to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you'll look into already made chat programs, like IntranetChat clone (http://dreamchat.sf.net) or IRC clients(www.visualirc.net). Well, the latter should be way to complex, but iChat might be nice starting point.

Comment: UDP broadcast would only work in most simple non-structured networks, and actually then you don't need server at all. If you rely on server - then you should ask server for listing clients and routing the messages.

Comment: @Arioch'The You are right, if we want to realize some own protocol fore usual IM features - we can use low-level sockets and do what we want. And it would be like UDP as low-level protocol behind HTTP as more high-level protocol. But I am not sure is it is right solution, for example, Pidgin used Purple library instead of something its own.

Comment: XMPP might be too feature-stuffed , too complex for him. IntraentChat - while limited on functionality - was very slick UI and had almost all the features chan in metropolitan LAN needed. So if topicstarter doesn ot want to take soem ready-made chat, then i guess DreamChat could be good starting point

Comment: @Abelisto, not at all. Someone who rely on UDP for data transfers can implement ACKs himself while retaining UDP broadcast powers for presence/discovery.

Answer (score 1):

TCP sockets work in both directions - a TCP server can initiate data transfer to the client on the same socket which the client used to connect to the server.

So to push the list of active connections to the client, the `IdTCPServer` simply iterates all connections and uses the `Connection.IOHandler.WriteXXX` methods to send the information. There is no technical difference between broadcasting the connection list data and broadcasting a new chat message to all clients.

The only requirement is that the data needs a "message type indicator" (one or more header bytes) which indicate the message type, optionally followed by the message body length and the data.